# In NixOS, if a new config requires rebuilding the kernel, will old configurations still work?

Tags: linux-kernel, nixos

The title really says it all, but just in case, here's some context:

Each time you change your configuration in NixOS, you need to run `nixos rebuild` to create a new boot image, which will be listed in Grub when you start the computer. A new configuration might require a new kernel. If it does, and you build it, will your old configurations continue to work?

[In Ubuntu it appears that one can](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437535/is-it-possible-that-i-have-more-than-one-linux-kernel-installed) indeed host multiple kernels on the same machine. And I read somewhere the linux kernel can be pretty small, like 60 MB. Those two facts lead me to expect NixOS will retain the old kernels. But I haven't found anything online that really makes that explicit.

I am currently building a configuration that uses [Musnix](https://github.com/musnix/musnix). If you ask for it, Musnix will build you a realtime kernel. I'm currently building [such a new configuration](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments/blob/audio/audio.nix), and hoping I'll still be able to boot my computer after it. I worry because GIthub user @magnetophon, who is involved in Musnix's development, [said](https://github.com/magnetophon/nixosConfig/issues/3#issuecomment-573753078) the Musnix realtime kernel is borken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cool features of NixOS. When you run `nixos-rebuild boot` (or `nixos-rebuild switch` too for that matter), it will create new boot entries alongside the old ones. These entries have the right kernel *and* system configuration in them. So if your experimental kernel doesn't work, you can just reboot and start a previous version of your system, knowing that it will work, even if your kernel also came with userland changes.

The `nixos-rebuild` command is documented here in the NixOS manual: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#sec-changing-config

Comment: When I first came to NixOS (and after reading the manual) I believed that old boot images would always keep working. Then I tried using [Musnix](https://github.com/musnix/musnix) as a channel, as described in its readme, and my entire system borked -- not just the new boot image, but all the others, too. Had to reinstall the OS. THe same thing [happend to someone else](https://github.com/musnix/musnix/issues/77#issuecomment-388841375).

Comment: At some point a script has to update the bootloader config and if that has a bad bug, I suppose that may screw up old entries too.